# Android Studio doesn't want to open project (macOS)

Tags: android, macos

Android Studio 3.4.2 can't open  project on macOS 10.15 Beta (19A526h)

Open Android Studio -> press `Open an existing Android Studio project` -> select folder with project -> NOTHING happens

I can create new project though, but can't open existing one.

Is there anything i missing here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: does the folder you selected contain build.gradle?

Comment: yep, it looks to be related to OS or some permissions idk which one, or some bug

Comment: i've just opened a project by dragging folder onto AndroidStudio directly, which brings import gradle project, which allows to open existing project

Comment: I can verify this problem.  Android Studio can't open projects using File\Open... but it will open newly created projects from the quickstart (recent) menu.  No big deal. jk.

Comment: Could it be related to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136592600 ? (not 100% sure, but that's a starting point).

Answer (score 3):

I have met the same problem. It works by dragging folder onto AndroidStudio directly.

Answer (score 0):

I made it easier to open projects with Finder by associating all `settings.gradle` files with Android Studio and then launching that file to open a project.  (I'm on Android Studio 4.2.2)

I find that Android Studio's behavior with launching project files is inconsistent.  If you don't have any project open and you launch a project's `gradle.properties` file with Android Studio, then it will open the whole project, BUT if you do this when another project is open then it will just open the `gradle.properties` text file in the already open project!  However, for some reason this issue is avoided with `settings.gradle` -- it always opens the whole project even if another project is already open.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs with macbook M1 macOS monterey. I solved this by,

1. Open Settings in Android Studio
2. Select Edit Custom VM options..
3. Add this line to it: `-Dide.mac.file.chooser.native=false`
4. Restart Android Studio