# Android Studio Open an existing Android Studio project doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio

I just upgraded Android Studio to v3.5 now `Open an existing Android Studio project` doesn't do anything. No error message or window. Same project which is listed on the left side of Welcome Screen opens without an error. I am using macOS Catalina and Android Studio to v3.5 I can't open any of my projects any more if it is not listed on the left side of welcome screen.

EDIT:
I don't know why you're down voting this question. This is a **BUG** on macOS. Here is same question with 3 upvotes. [Android Studio doesn't want to open project (macOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57348433/android-studio-doesnt-want-to-open-project-macos) I am trying to find an answer.

Comment: check your internet activity in something similar to a task manager... sorry idk what a mac has but sometimes AS is downloading something and will open the project after thats done

Comment: Project can be opened if it is on the left side of welcome screen. Project works. I can create projects. Gradle syncs everything is working. It's just `Open an existing Android Studio project` doesn't do anything anymore. Maybe it is a macOS bug.

Comment: I have the same bug. I don't know the reason why it happens yet, maybe it's something related to macOS Catalina, and will be fixed in the next beta update. However, I solved this problem by dragging the project folder directly into Android Studio on the welcome screen.

Comment: You're using beta software (android studio 3.5) on top of even more beta software (macOS catalina, known for being one of the buggiest beta releases in the last few years), I'd say this is a bug in either or both. I did not downvote, but this question (and judging by the sole answer at the moment) won't serve much purpose here on SO and the mods may hammer it. Good luck finding the solution though. (I shouldn't but more and more I feel the need to clarify: No, I didn't downvote; I rarely do). (I know AS 3.5 got "stable" but... that doesn't mean "tested on catalina")

Comment: For what is worth, I updated my AS 3.4 to 3.5 and it works fine (but I'm running Linux).

Comment: Android Studio 3.5 became stable *today* (or yesterday), August 21st 2019. macOS Catalina is still in Beta. Chances are (and it's now confirmed) this is a bug in either AS or macOS. Yes, it's just become stable, but that doesn't mean it's tried and tested like the 3.4.x branch, nor that it's supposed to work fine with unreleased versions of macOS. All I was saying is that you're testing v 1.0 releases (3.5 is new) against beta (and known for being buggy) OSes. I'd just delete this, since the duplicate has the same information. ;)

Comment: The downvote comment was because _more often than not_, original posters *demand* to know why they got downvotes and blindly accuse commenters. I didn't say you did, I just merely -out of having being bitten over 9000 times- _clarified_ that it was not me.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini whenever I reply, my replies are deleted. I guess I shouldn't talk back to bullies anymore. Cheers.

Comment: @Meanteacher no idea how or who can delete replies, sorry to hear about that. Cheers.